# How to loop through json and replace values with grep & sed in multiple files

Tags: sed, terminal, grep

I got a reference json file called `reference.json` with key/values that I want to replace in `.html` files.

```
{
    "a.js": "first.1a.js",
    "b.js": "second.2b.js",
    "c.js": "third.3b.js"
}
```

Then I got 3 different html files

`test1.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ..
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h1>file 1</h1>

  </div>

  <script src="a.js"></script>
  <script src="b.js"></script>
  <script src="c.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`test2.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h1>file 2</h1>

  </div>

  <script src="a.js"></script>
  <script src="b.js"></script>
  <script src="c.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And a file in a folder `folder1/test3.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ...
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h1>file 3</h1>

  </div>

  <script src="../js/a.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/b.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/c.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I search through all of my .html files and replace with values from my json with grep and sed?

Comment: show your attempt

Comment: Why do you want to use sed here? It's much more solvable with AWK or other tools. Moreover, your test1.html and test2.html are almost identical, so including both files into your question provides no additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your reference.json is well formatted, this one-liner will do it for you :

```
$ CMD=" sed -i $( cat reference.json | grep ":" | sed 's/ //g;s/,//g;s/"//g' | sed 's/:/\//g' | awk '{printf("s/%s/g;",$0)}' )" && find . -name "*.html" -exec ${CMD} {} \;
```

Explanation :

Use the reference.json to form an sed substitution expression to use it in an sed command. Use find command to find all the "*.html" files and perform the substitution.

If the reference.json is not formatted, you can use the following command to format it :

```
$ python -m json.tool reference.json
```